# WP plugins install errors

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, syntax-error

We are getting errors when trying to install a WordPress Plugin.

We reached out to the plugin maker, but have not heard back from them.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in
> /homepages/44/d839257894/htdocs/clickandbuilds/000+/wp-content/plugins/woofunnels-aero-checkout/woofunnels/includes/class-woofunnels-license-check.php
> on line 238

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do:

- Check if your Plugins' PHP files are corrupted or broken

  - Make a clean re-download of the Plugin
- If the files are o.k., the Plugin is broken

  - Possibility 1: Wait for an update
  - Possibility 2: Go into the PHP files of the Plugin and fix them (path is part of the error message)

Comment: Thanks Blackbam, Was able to fixe it.